# Update and delete in one event scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

I am creating a room reservation in php.

I have two tables:

table `RESERVE`

- reserve_id
- room_id
- room_reserve_qty
- checkout

table `ROOM`

- room_id
- room_qty

when the "checkout" date reached the date today,that row in the reserve table will be deleted.Actually I already have the event for that :

```
DROP EVENT `auto_delete_chckout`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
EVENT `auto_delete_chckout` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2013-01-26 13:09:15' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
DELETE FROM reserve WHERE checkout <= CURDATE()
```

so my question is :

If a *reservation is being deleted* , its `room_reserve_qty` *must be added* in the `room_qty` in room table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you probably don't need to fire your event every minute, since you check only for a date part. You might want to do that once a day.

Secondly I would put updating `room_qty` logic in a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html). That way no matter how you delete your reservation, your `room_qty` will be correct.

Your trigger might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER reserve_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON reserve
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE room
           SET room_qty = room_qty + OLD.room_reserve_qty 
         WHERE room_id = OLD.room_id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Your `DELETE` code stays intact when you use a trigger.

Comment: oh, I just set it to 1 minute because I'm currently testing it if it really works.

Comment: if that's the case you need to manually delete the record so the trigger will fire. right?

Answer (score 1):

before you delete the records on table `reserve`, you need to update the records of table `room` first so you will know which `room_id` will be updated, eg

```
UPDATE  room a
        INNER JOIN reserve b
            ON a.room_id = b.room_id
SET     a.room_qty = a.room_qty + b.room_reserve_qty
WHERE   b.checkout <= CURDATE();

DELETE FROM reserve WHERE checkout <= CURDATE();
```

full code:

```
DROP EVENT `auto_delete_chckout`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `auto_delete_chckout` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2013-01-26 13:09:15' 
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  room a
                    INNER JOIN reserve b
                        ON a.room_id = b.room_id
            SET     a.room_qty = a.room_qty + b.room_reserve_qty
            WHERE   b.checkout <= CURDATE();

            DELETE FROM reserve WHERE checkout <= CURDATE();
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

Since you mentioned that you are new, `Event`, *I think*, causes to much work on the server. A `TRIGGER` might be the other way. A `Trigger` is basically a block of code that is fired every time an event (*before or after*) is happening on the table, eg: `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and exact answer :D

Yep, I am currently exploring around event,cron job and triggers now.